# When processing Java mode convert to Java script mode, my 3D object doesn't show

Tags: java, javascript, processing

I have a problem when I upload my sketch to website.

I write a processing program which is a 3D guiding library.This is my code.

```
  //Camera Variables
    float x,y,z;
    float tx,ty,tz;
    float rotX,rotY;
    float mX, mY;
    float frameCounter;
    float xComp, zComp;
    float angle;

  //Movement Variables
    int moveX;
    int moveZ;
    float vY;
    boolean canJump;
    boolean moveUP,moveDOWN,moveLEFT,moveRIGHT;


    //check input
    int m =0;

//Constants
  int ground = 0;
  int totalBoxes = 100;
  int standHeight = 100;
  int dragMotionConstant = 10;
  int pushMotionConstant = 100;
  int movementSpeed = 50;    //Bigger number = slower
  float sensitivity = 15;      //Bigger number = slower
  int stillBox = 100;        //Center of POV, mouse must be stillBox away from center to move
  float camBuffer = 10;
  int cameraDistance = 1000;  //distance from camera to camera target in lookmode... 8?

//Options
  int lookMode = 8;
  int spotLightMode = 4;
  int cameraMode = 1;
  int moveMode = 2;

void setup(){
  size(800,600,P3D);
  noStroke(); 
  //dwa(#EDEDE8);

  //Camera Initialization

  //default
  x = -28;
  y = height/2;
    y-= standHeight;
  z = -4830;
  tx = width/2;
  ty = height/2;
  tz = 0;
  rotX = 0;
  rotY = 0;
  xComp = tx - x;
  zComp = tz - z;
  angle = 0;

  //Movement Initialization
  moveX = 0;
  moveX = 0;
  moveUP = false;
  moveDOWN = false;
  moveLEFT = false;
  moveRIGHT = false;  
  canJump = true;
  vY = 0;



}


void draw(){
  if(z<-5000)
  z=-5000;

  if(z>9700)
  z=9700;



  //println(x,y,z ,mouseX , mouseY ,tx ,ty,tz);
  //update frame
  background(0);
  lights();


  if(m==1)
  {
    //rotateY(0.5);
 fill(#EAFF0F);
  textSize(50);
  text("menu", x-100, y, z+300); 

 // rotateY(0.5);

         //the point
    pushMatrix();     
     fill(#FC1919);
     translate(-28,300,4000);
    box(10, 20000, -10);
    popMatrix();   
    //the point

  }



  if(spotLightMode == 0)
    lights();
  else if(spotLightMode == 1)
    spotLight(255,255,255,x,y-standHeight,z,tx,ty,tz,PI,1);
  else if(spotLightMode == 2)
    spotLight(255,255,255,x,y-standHeight-200,z,x+100,y+100,z,frameCounter/10,1);
  else if(spotLightMode == 3)
    spotLight(255,255,255,width/2,height/2-1000,0,width/2,height/2,0,PI,1);
  else if(spotLightMode == 4)
  {
    pointLight(255,255,255,x,y,z);

  }

    /*
    for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {
    spotLight(255, 255, 255, -28, 2000, -5500+i*1875, 1, 1, 1, 360, 1);
    }*/
    //-5500 9500s



  //back wall
 pushMatrix();     
 fill(255);
  translate(-28,300,-5500);
    box(15000, 5000, -100);
    popMatrix();
    //back wall

      //fount wall
 pushMatrix();     
 fill(255);
  translate(-28,300,10500);
    box(15000, 5000, -100);
    popMatrix();
    //fount wall


    //L1
  bookshielf(800,-4000,7,1);
  bookshielf(1000,-4000,7,1);
  bookshielf(1200,-4000,7,1);
  bookshielf(1400,-4000,7,1);


 cameraUpdate();
  locationUpdate();
  jumpManager(10);



  //Camera Mode 1 - Original
  if(cameraMode == 1)
    camera(x,y,z,tx,ty,tz,0,1,0);

  //Camera Mode 2 - Matrix'd
 /* if(cameraMode == 2){
    beginCamera();
      camera();
      translate(x,y,z);
      translate(0,2*-standHeight,0);

      rotateX(rotY/100.0); //This seems to work o.o
      rotateY(-rotX/100.0);
      //rotateX(rotX/100.0);
    endCamera();
  }*/

  //frameCounter++;



}


void cylinder(float w, float h, int sides)
{
  float angle;
  float[] x = new float[sides+1];
  float[] z = new float[sides+1];
 translate(0,100,-500);
  //get the x and z position on a circle for all the sides
  for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++){
    angle = TWO_PI / (sides) * i;
    x[i] = sin(angle) * w;
    z[i] = cos(angle) * w;
  }

  //draw the top of the cylinder
  beginShape(TRIANGLE_FAN);

  vertex(0,   -h/2,    0);

  for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++){
    vertex(x[i], -h/2, z[i]);
  }

  endShape();

  //draw the center of the cylinder
  beginShape(QUAD_STRIP); 

  for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++){
    vertex(x[i], -h/2, z[i]);
    vertex(x[i], h/2, z[i]);
  }

  endShape();

  //draw the bottom of the cylinder
  beginShape(TRIANGLE_FAN); 

  vertex(0,   h/2,    0);

  for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++){
    vertex(x[i], h/2, z[i]);
  }

  endShape();
}

public void bookshielf(int thex ,int thez ,int theheight ,int therotate)
{
  fill(#938056);

  if(theheight==7)
  {
    if(therotate==1)
    {
    //left
  pushMatrix();
   translate(thex,0,thez);
    box(20, 500, -100);
    popMatrix();

    //right
     pushMatrix();
  translate(thex-200,0,thez);
    box(20, 500, -100);
    popMatrix();

    //back
     pushMatrix();     
  translate(thex-100,0,thez+40);
    box(220, 500, -30);
    popMatrix();

    //middle side
    for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
    {
     pushMatrix();     
  translate(thex-100,-250+71.5*i,thez-10);
    box(220, 5, -100);
    popMatrix();
    }

    //top
      pushMatrix();     
  translate(thex-100,250,thez);
    box(220, 10, -100);
    popMatrix();

    //block
      pushMatrix();     
  translate(thex-100,-250,thez);
    box(220, 10, -100);
    popMatrix();

  }

  if(therotate==2)
  {
     //left
  pushMatrix();
   translate(thex,0,thez);
    box(20, 500, -100);
    popMatrix();

    //right
     pushMatrix();
  translate(thex-200,0,thez);
    box(20, 500, -100);
    popMatrix();

    //back
     pushMatrix();     
  translate(thex-100,0,thez-40);
    box(220, 500, -30);
    popMatrix();

    //middle side
    for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
    {
     pushMatrix();     
  translate(thex-100,-250+71.5*i,thez+10);
    box(220, 5, -100);
    popMatrix();
    }

    //top
      pushMatrix();     
  translate(thex-100,250,thez);
    box(220, 10, -100);
    popMatrix();

    //block
      pushMatrix();     
  translate(thex-100,-250,thez);
    box(220, 10, -100);
    popMatrix();

  }
}
}



public void cameraUpdate(){
  ty=constrain(dragMotionConstant, -100000, 500000);
  //Drag-motion
  if (lookMode == 1){
    if(pmouseX > mouseX)
      tx += dragMotionConstant;
    else if (pmouseX < mouseX)
      tx -= dragMotionConstant; 
    if(pmouseY > mouseY)
      ty -= dragMotionConstant/1.5;
    else if (pmouseY < mouseY)
      ty += dragMotionConstant/1.5;
  }


  //Push-motion
  else if (lookMode == 2){
    if (mouseX > (width/2+pushMotionConstant))
      tx += dragMotionConstant;
    else if (mouseX < (width/2-pushMotionConstant))
      tx -= dragMotionConstant;
    if (mouseY > (height/2+pushMotionConstant))
      ty += dragMotionConstant;
    else if (mouseY < (height/2-pushMotionConstant))
      ty -= dragMotionConstant;
  }

  //Push-motion V2 (Hopefully improved!)
  else if (lookMode == 3){
    int diffX = mouseX - width/2;
    int diffY = mouseY - width/2;

    if (abs(diffX) > pushMotionConstant)
      tx += diffX/25;
    if (abs(diffY) > pushMotionConstant)
      ty += diffY/25;
  }

  //Push Motion V3 (For Camera-Mode 2)
  else if (lookMode == 4){
    int diffX = mouseX - width/2;
    int diffY = mouseY - width/2;
  //println(diffX);
  if (abs(diffX) > pushMotionConstant)
      rotX += diffX/100;
    if (abs(diffY) > pushMotionConstant)
      rotY += diffY/100;//diffY/100;
  }

  //Push Motion V4.1 (Because it crashed and I lost V4.0 T.T
  //Designed to work in cohesion with movement mode 2
  else if (lookMode == 5){
    int diffX = mouseX - width/2;
    int diffY = mouseY - width/2;

    if(abs(diffX) > stillBox){
      xComp = tx - x;
      zComp = tz - z;
      angle = degrees(atan(xComp/zComp));

      //---------DEBUG STUFF GOES HERE----------
      //println("tx:    " + tx);
      //println("tz:    " + tz);
     // println("xC:    " + xComp);
     // println("zC:    " + zComp);
     // println("Angle: " +angle);
      //--------------------------------------*/

      if (angle < 45 && angle > -45 && zComp < 0)
        tx += diffX/sensitivity;
      else if (angle < 45 && angle > -45 && zComp > 0)
        tx -= diffX/sensitivity;

      //Left Sector
      else if (angle > 45 && angle < 90 && xComp < 0 && zComp < 0)
        tz -= diffX/sensitivity;
      else if (angle >-90 && angle <-45 && xComp < 0 && zComp > 0)
        tz -= diffX/sensitivity;

      //Right Sector
      else if (angle <-45 && angle >-90)
        tz += diffX/sensitivity;
      else if (angle < 90 && angle > 45 && xComp > 0 && zComp > 0)
        tz += diffX/sensitivity;
    }

    if (abs(diffY) > stillBox)
      ty += diffY/(sensitivity/1.5);
  }

  //Lookmode 4.2
  //Using a more proper unit circle.
  else if (lookMode == 6){
    int diffX = mouseX - width/2;
    int diffY = mouseY - width/2;

    if(abs(diffX) > stillBox){
      xComp = tx - x;
      zComp = tz - z;
      angle = correctAngle(xComp,zComp);

      //---------DEBUG STUFF GOES HERE----------
     // println("tx:    " + tx);
     // println("tz:    " + tz);
     // println("xC:    " + xComp);
     /// println("zC:    " + zComp);
     /// println("Angle: " +angle);
      //--------------------------------------*/

      //Looking 'forwards'
      if ((angle >= 0 && angle < 45) || (angle > 315 && angle < 360))
        tx += diffX/sensitivity;

      //Looking 'left'
      else if (angle > 45 && angle < 135)
        tz += diffX/sensitivity;

      //Looking 'back'
      else if (angle > 135 && angle < 225)
        tx -= diffX/sensitivity;

      //Looking 'right'
      else if (angle > 225 && angle < 315)
        tz -= diffX/sensitivity;

    }

    if (abs(diffY) > stillBox)
      ty += diffY/(sensitivity/1.5);
  }

  //Lookmode 7, trying to get rid of the slowdown in the corners with a sorta-buffer thing
  else if (lookMode == 7){
    int diffX = mouseX - width/2;
    int diffY = mouseY - width/2;

    if(abs(diffX) > stillBox){
      xComp = tx - x;
      zComp = tz - z;
      angle = correctAngle(xComp,zComp);

      //---------DEBUG STUFF GOES HERE----------
     // println("tx:    " + tx);
     // println("tz:    " + tz);
     // println("xC:    " + xComp);
     // println("zC:    " + zComp);
     // println("Angle: " +angle);
      //--------------------------------------*/

      //Looking 'forwards'
      if ((angle >= 0-camBuffer && angle < 45+camBuffer) || (angle > 315-camBuffer && angle < 360+camBuffer))
        tx += diffX/sensitivity;

      //Looking 'left'
      else if (angle > 45-camBuffer && angle < 135+camBuffer)
        tz += diffX/sensitivity;

      //Looking 'back'
      else if (angle > 135-camBuffer && angle < 225+camBuffer)
        tx -= diffX/sensitivity;

      //Looking 'right'
      else if (angle > 225-camBuffer && angle < 315+camBuffer)
        tz -= diffX/sensitivity;

    }

    if (abs(diffY) > stillBox)
      ty += diffY/(sensitivity/1.5);
  }

  else if (lookMode == 8){
    int diffX = mouseX - width/2;
    int diffY = mouseY - width/2;

    if(abs(diffX) > stillBox){
      xComp = tx - x;
      zComp = tz - z;
      angle = correctAngle(xComp,zComp);

      angle+= diffX/(sensitivity*10);

      if(angle < 0)
        angle += 360;
      else if (angle >= 360)
        angle -= 360;

      float newXComp = cameraDistance * sin(radians(angle));
      float newZComp = cameraDistance * cos(radians(angle));

      tx = newXComp + x;
      tz = -newZComp + z;

      //---------DEBUG STUFF GOES HERE----------
      /*println("tx:    " + tx);
      println("tz:    " + tz);
      println("xC:    " + xComp);
      println("NewXC: " + newXComp);
      println("zC:    " + zComp);
      println("NewZC: " + newZComp);
      println("Angle: " +angle);*/
      //--------------------------------------*/

    }

    if (abs(diffY) > stillBox)
      ty += diffY/(sensitivity/1.5);
  }


}

public void locationUpdate(){

  /*Old method==================================
  if(keyPressed){
    if (keyCode == UP || key == 'w'){
      z-=10;
      tz-=10;
    }
    else if (keyCode == DOWN || key == 's'){
      tz+=10;
      z+=10;
    }
    else if (keyCode == LEFT || key == 'a' ){
      tx-=10;
      x-=10;
    }
    else if (keyCode == RIGHT || key == 'd'){
      tx+=10;
      x+=10;
    }
  }
  ============================================*/

  //Apply Movement
  if(moveMode == 1){
    z += moveZ;
    tz += moveZ;
    x += moveX;
    tx += moveX;
  }
  else if(moveMode == 2){
    if(moveUP){
      z += zComp/movementSpeed;
      tz+= zComp/movementSpeed;
      x += xComp/movementSpeed;
      tx+= xComp/movementSpeed;
    }
    else if(moveDOWN){
      z -= zComp/movementSpeed;
      tz-= zComp/movementSpeed;
      x -= xComp/movementSpeed;
      tx-= xComp/movementSpeed;
    }
    if (moveRIGHT){
      z += xComp/movementSpeed; 
      tz+= xComp/movementSpeed;
      x -= zComp/movementSpeed;
      tx-= zComp/movementSpeed;
    }
    if (moveLEFT){
      z -= xComp/movementSpeed; 
      tz-= xComp/movementSpeed;
      x += zComp/movementSpeed;
      tx+= zComp/movementSpeed;
    }

  }
  //New method also uses keyPressed() and keyReleased()
  // Scroll Down! 
}

public void jumpManager(int magnitude){
  /*
  if(keyPressed && key == ' ' && canJump){
    vY -= magnitude;
    if(vY < -20)
      canJump = false;
  }
  else*/ if (y < ground+standHeight)
    vY ++;
  else if (y >= ground+standHeight){
    vY = 0;
    y = ground + standHeight;
  }

  if((!canJump) && (!keyPressed)){
    //println("Jump Reset!");
    canJump = true;
  }

  y += vY;
}





public void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP || key == 'w'){
    moveZ = -10;
    moveUP = true;
  }

  else if(keyCode == DOWN || key == 's'){
    moveZ = 10;
    moveDOWN = true;
  }

  else if(keyCode == LEFT || key == 'a'){
    moveX = -10;
    moveLEFT = true;
  }

  else if(keyCode == RIGHT || key == 'd'){
    moveX = 10;
    moveRIGHT = true;
  }

    if(key == 'm' && m==1){

    m=0;
  }
  else if(key == 'm' && m==0){

    if(key == '1')

    {


    }
    rotateY(180);
     fill(#EAFF0F);
  textSize(50);
  text("menu", x-100, y, z+300); 
    m=1;


  }


}

public void keyReleased(){
  if(keyCode == UP || key == 'w'){
    moveUP = false;
    moveZ = 0;
  }
  else if(keyCode == DOWN || key == 's'){
    moveDOWN = false;
    moveZ = 0;
  }

  else if(keyCode == LEFT || key == 'a'){
    moveLEFT = false;
    moveX = 0;
  }

  else if(keyCode == RIGHT || key == 'd'){
    moveRIGHT = false;
    moveX = 0;
  }


}

void mousePressed()
{


}




public float correctAngle(float xc, float zc){
  float newAngle = -degrees(atan(xc/zc));
  if (xComp > 0 && zComp > 0)
    newAngle = (90 + newAngle)+90;
  else if (xComp < 0 && zComp > 0)
    newAngle = newAngle + 180;
  else if (xComp < 0 && zComp < 0)
    newAngle = (90+ newAngle) + 270;
  return newAngle;
}
```

People can use their first person view to walk the library.It is fine in java mode,but when I put it in java script mode,the view has problem.So , which part of my code has problems so that it can not run on website?
Thank you very much.

Comment: java is not javascript, you cannot directly copy from java file to a javascript file.

Comment: so what can I do to upload my current job no matter website,applications,applet.... to public?

Comment: You might be able to use an applet or GWT. I'd probably learn JS if I were you though.

Comment: javaScript mode does use [procesing.js](http://processingjs.org/reference/) to convert proccesing's code to js. There are some differences and not supported stuff though. Check their documentation. int divisions, overloading methods are common mistakes. Use a browser to debug js version...